# Any guide to implement Azure Search with Sitecore 8.1x?

Tags: azure-search

Is there a way to implement Azure Search with Sitecore 8.1x? Currently I can see only one option to update current Sitecore instance to 8.2x.

Comment: Update to Sitecore 8.2x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box Azure Search is only available on Sitecore 8.2 update 1 and above.

If you wanted to use it on earlier versions you would have to write your own provider for it.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie Scott has implemented Azure Search for Sitecore 8.1. However this is not officially supported by Sitecore. Here is the git repo for the same.
https://github.com/jscott1277/SitecoreAzureSearchProvider